# pharo - run a code when server starts

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

I am using ZnZincServerAdapter and have a web server. I now want to make sure that when I start this server there should be a piece of code that gets executed. how can this be done ?

basically i have a web app in smalltalk so I when I go to that URL , i want the previous heavy piece of code to be executed when I start my server and not when I load my page.

Answer (score 7):

You can this from within the image or when you start it. For within the image have a look at

> Smalltalk>>#addToStartUpList:

This registers a class that will be executed when the image starts. You need to implement the methods startUp: and shutDown: in your class. Those will be called on start/stop of the image.

Or you can do it when starting the image. If you provide an argument (needs to be the first argument) to the image that is a file (absolute path necessary) the image will read the file in and execute it

Comment: I found another way since I was using ZnZincServerAdapter I used its start method. thanks.